# Is it possible to use the whole data frame as predictor in R?

Tags: r

For example, I have a 4x3 data frame:

```
           Weight     Color       Shape
Apple        0.1       Pink       heart
Orange       0.2       Orange    sphere
Strawberry   0.01      White      heart
Watermelon   1.72      Green      square
```

and I would like the output to be Japan (country). All the formation is important here, so is it possible to use the whole data frame to predict one value (Japan).

Comment: This doesn't really make sense to me, perhaps I'm missing something obvious. Are you using a regression technique? ML? What are you doing where you can use its output to predict an outcome? (Lacking anything else, `mypredict <- function(...) return("Japan"); mypredict(thisdat);` will predict "Japan" with 100% accuracy.)

Comment: Ummm, so I want the output to be Japan

Comment: basically, I have many dataset like this and some of them correspond to the US, China, Australia....etc  I know the countries of 70% of the data, and I want to predict the countries of the 30% with this format of the data.

Comment: According to what you've provided, my function above will predict "Japan" for you. I don't know if you're doing linear, logistic, multi-logistic, mixed-effects, or one of many other types of regression on this data to be able to classify this data as belonging to "Japan". Do you know what type of classification/regression you intend to run?

Comment: Not really, I had only deal with single column prediction (linear and logistic) before. Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: I am inferring that your question is *"how do I use multiple rows in a frame to get one classification?"* If it is always the same number of rows, then you should be able to reshape the frame from 4 rows to 1 (with 12 columns) and look at classification engines from there. If the number of rows vary, then ... yeah, not a clue. You may get better help at [stats.se].

Comment: That's exactly my question! Thank you, I will get some help at CV!